# What is the best way to work on a MVC project online?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a regular Web Forms application, I could upload the files to a web server and just open the web server in Visual Web Developer and it worked great, but because MVC is a project and not a     web application, I can't just upload the files regulary and still open it in Visual Web Developre normally...

So here comes the SVN, but the problem is that I can't show the web site before publish to my boss... Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio comes with a mini web server built-in that lets you run any ASP.NET project locally. You should just be able to press F5 and it'll run (as long as you've got things like database connections and so on set up properly).

Comment: I don't have VS everywhere... and I need it in some places that have no VS